# Nested for loop adds to the list double the amount of times its supposed to

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, key-value

I'm trying to iterate over my two LINQ queries using foreach nested loop pattern and then add the elements to the `KeyValuePair` instance of a list:

LINQ queries:

```
var nameQuery = org.deltagerRelation
    .SelectMany(r => r.Deltager ?? new List<Deltager>())
    .Where(a => a.Enhedstype != null && a.Enhedstype == "PERSON")
    .SelectMany(d => d.Navne)
    .Select(n => n.Navn);

var boardMembersQuery = org.deltagerRelation
    .SelectMany(o => o.Organisationer ?? new List<Organisationer>())
    .SelectMany(m => m.MedlemsData)
    .SelectMany(a => a.Attributter)
    .SelectMany(v => v.Vaerdier)
    .Where(v => v.Vaerdi != null && v.Vaerdi == "BESTYRELSE")
    .Select(v => v.Vaerdi);
```

And the ouput I get is as expected, the `nameQuery` returns two names and the `boardMembersQuery` returns two board members. However, when I run them through nested foreach loop like this:

```
foreach(var name in nameQuery)
{
    foreach(var boardMember in boardMembersQuery)
    {
        result.BoardMembers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, JToken>(name, boardMember));
    }
}
```

Each of the query values gets added two times to the list, and I end up having four key/value pairs instead of two. Is the pattern of for each loops implemented incorrectly or is there something else going on that I'm missing?

Comment: Your outer loop iterates twice, and your inner loop iterates twice for each iteration of the outer loop - why would you expect to get only two entries? You've got *every* name against *every* board member. It's not clear which two entries you'd expect...

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have 4 key-value pairs.

NameQuery has 2 results.

boardMemberQuery has 2 results.

The outer loop runs 2 times, and the inner loop runs 2 times per outer loop execution

2x2=4

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured that I do not really need a nested foreach loop pattern, I just decided to use the Zip method on my LINQ query results:

```
var combinedResult = nameQuery.Zip(boardMembersQuery, (n, b) => new { Name = n, BoardMember = b });
```

and just iterated over the `combinedResult` and added the properties to the list!